# Reject button not working on the second click

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, javascript

The Reject button cannot be clicked again when closing the Reject screen using <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

### Steps to reproduce

- Visit the [Suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) screen (or an individual suggested edit).
- Hit the Reject button *(a screen appears)*.
- Use <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close the Reject screen.
- Hit any Reject button (= not necessarily the just-clicked one).
- The following message(s) shows up in my console:

> **Firefox 9**:
> c is null
> Line 1, http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=3daa464d05b5
>
> **Chrome 17**
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
> stub.js:1

The error might be related to the recent jQuery upgrade. I located the error to be at `StackExchange.init.createJqueryExtensions`:

```js
center: function () {
    var d = this.parent();
    if (d.css("position") === "static") {
        d = d.offsetParent()
    }
    // Apparently, d is not an element, and the following line returns undefined
    var c = d.offset();
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2
                   + $(window).scrollTop() - c.top + "px");
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2
                    + $(window).scrollLeft() - c.left + "px");
    return this
},
```

*Side note, this piece code can be optimized by storing `$(window)` in a temporary variable, since it's called four times.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the diagnostics, surprisingly this is not a bug related to the jQuery upgrade. It has been there since I initially implemented it.

Fixed now.

The escape key was removing the prototype for the rejection dialog.

Comment: fyi, not deployed yet